# running a pytest hook only once on the start of the tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, hook, pytest

I'm having a pytest run that invokes N tests. I want all tests to output into the same log, and I want to clear the log before pytest is triggered, so different runs would not contiminate each other. So far, I tried adding my `clear_log()` to some fixtures or hooks, but none has achieved what In wanted - or they were called each time (`pytest_runtest_makereport` for example), or they were not called at all (some function that was decorated with `pytest.fixture()`

I also tried having a global flag that would indicate if this is the first run, but it didn't work either...

Where can I put the function so it would be invoked only once?

Answer (score 1):

Following decorator allows you to execute your fixture only once (even if there are multiple number of tests are running):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
```

More details [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)

Comment: This will call the fixture once for each module. It should be `scope="session"`.